# Javascript get string occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to return how many times the string `s.t()` was found in a string, but I can't get the correct regex for this...

For example

```
var string = 'function(test) {s.t(); s.t(dsabf); s.t();}'
var re = new RegExp('s\.t\(\)', "g");
return re;
```

should return an array of 2 elements `['s.t()', 's.t()']` but instead it has 3 elements `['s.t', 's.t', 's.t']`

I've also tried with `^s\t\(\)$` but this returns no match...

How can I fix my regex in order to make this work as expected?

Comment: Looking for literal texts using a regex you should consider [escaping the strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript).

Comment: The backslashes in the string you're passing `new RegExp` don't end up being backslashes in the pattern, because they're processed by the string literal. Either use a regex literal: `var re = /s\.t\(\)/g;` or escape them so they're really backslashes: `var re = new RegExp('s\\.t\\(\\)', "g");` (You don't actually have to escape the `)` when it's not in a group, but...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that makes a lot of sense, it works now